# Google Chrome show different setting options when print to PDF

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, settings

I tried to print some webpage in PDF using Chrome print function. But I need to set the page size as Legal. I found that can not set the page size if I choose "Save as PDF" option.

[image: some webpage it do not have size option]

But when I tried this print in other website, I found Chrome dose have that option.
[image: some webpage it have size option]
Why Chrome showing different options? I am using the same Chrome. How can I get to set the paper size in every web page?

Answer (score 1):

After inspect the html, I found that the css setting

```
@page{size: letter}
```

if remove all @page setting chrome will show size option